# How can I define state based on another state property?

Tags: reactjs, state

I come from the Ember world so apologies if this question is very basic (I'm sure it is). I have a component which sets the state "scrollPosition" whenever the window is scrolled. I would like to define a new state property, "isScrolledToTop", which is equal to true when "scrollPosition" is 0.

In Ember I would have simple defined a new property and checked the condition when scrollPosition changed. Not quite sure how to do this in React. I was thinking of using "componentDidUpdate", but pretty sure this is not the right approach. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update style of a component onScroll in React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js)

Comment: Thanks I saw this earlier. This was great for learning how to add event listeners and update one state.

What I'm interesting in now is more generally, how can I update one state property when another changes

Comment: Maybe this isn't the answer you're looking for, but couldn't you set the second state variable in the same function that updates the scrollPosition state?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "how can I fire some event once the user scrolls to the top of the page" then the answer is to do that in the `onscroll` event callback.

If you want to *render* something differently (e.g. a full-size header) when the scroll position is at the top of the page, then the logic would go in the `render()` method of your component. Something like:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.scrollPosition === 0) {
    // do something specific to this scenario
  }
  return ...
}
```

[This part](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state) of the docs suggests *not* putting 'computed data' in state, which is what `isScrolledToTop` is.

As an FYI, if you're tracking the scroll position, the window object keeps this in its 'state' for you, available at `window.scrollY` - you don't need to duplicate this into your component's state.