# Toggle Class based on scroll React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, events, dom-events

I'm using bootstrap 4 nav bar and would like to change the background color after ig 400px down scroll down. I was looking at the react docs and found a onScroll but couldn't find that much info on it. So far I have...

I don't know if I'm using the right event listener or how to set the height etc.

And I'm not really setting inline styles...

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';

   class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      this.state = {  scrollBackground: 'nav-bg' };
      this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
   }


   handleScroll(){
      this.setState ({
         scrollBackground: !this.state.scrollBackground
       })
    }

 render() {
 const scrollBg = this.scrollBackground ? 'nav-bg scrolling' : 'nav-bg';

 return (
   <div>

       <Navbar inverse toggleable className={this.state.scrollBackground} 
                                  onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
        ...
      </Navbar>

    </div>
   );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update style of a component onScroll in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js)

Comment: I tried going with what they had but didn't work for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way to add a scroll listener is to use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. Following example should give you an idea:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isTop: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;
      if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
          this.setState({ isTop })
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '200vh' }}>
        <h2 style={{ position: 'fixed', top: 0 }}>Scroll {this.state.isTop ? 'down' : 'up'}!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This changes the Text from "Scroll down" to "Scroll up" when your scrollY position is at 100 and above.

Edit: Should avoid the overkill of updating the state on each scroll. Only update it when the boolean value changes.

Comment: thanks Glenn, that worked thanks, i modified it to my code incase anyone ever has the same questions 

`<Navbar inverse toggleable 
style={{ top: 0 }} 
className={this.state.isTop ? 'pt-3 sticky-top nav-bg' : 'pt-3 sticky-top nav-bg scrolling'}
>`

Comment: I have this warning after adding this code:
`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.`

Answer (score 35):

For those of you who are **reading this question after 2020**, I've taken @glennreyes answer and rewritten it using **React Hooks**:

```
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      const scrollCheck = window.scrollY < 100
      if (scrollCheck !== scroll) {
        setScroll(scrollCheck)
      }
    })
  })
```

Bear in mind that, **useState** has an array of two elements, firstly the **state object** and secondly the **function that updates it**.

Along the lines, **useEffect** helps us replace **componentDidmount**, the function written currently does not do any clean ups for brevity purposes.

If you find it essential to clean up, you can just return a function inside the **useEffect**.

You can read comprehensively [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

**UPDATE:**

If you guys felt like making it **modular** and even do the **clean up**, you can do something like this:

1. Create a **custom hook** as below;

   ```
   import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

   export const useScrollHandler = () => {
   // setting initial value to true
   const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(1)

   // running on mount
   useEffect(() => {
     const onScroll = () => {
       const scrollCheck = window.scrollY < 10
       if (scrollCheck !== scroll) {
         setScroll(scrollCheck)
       }
     }

   // setting the event handler from web API
   document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)

   // cleaning up from the web API
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
     }
   }, [scroll, setScroll])

   return scroll

   }
   ```
2. **Call it inside any component** that you find suitable:

   ```
   const component = () => {

   // calling our custom hook
   const scroll = useScrollHandler()

   ....... rest of your code

   }
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't the cleanup be `document.removeEventListener`?

Comment: I think you might need to put in an example of what `....... rest of your code` would be. What type does useScrollHandler return? A number? A bool? it's not super obvious, and then how do you use that data to make something appear or dissappear?

Comment: scrollCheck is a boolean and scroll is a number

Comment: @Sam Hey mate, Thanks for commenting types here.

Answer (score 7):

```
 const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setScroll(window.scrollY > specify_height_you_want_to_change_after_here);
   });
 }, []);
```

Then you can change your class or anything according to scroll.

```
<nav className={scroll ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"}>...</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks it is easy to use

Answer (score 5):

It's Better

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isTop: true
    };
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;
      if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
        this.onScroll(isTop);
      }
    });
  }

  onScroll(isTop) {
    this.setState({ isTop });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '200vh' }}>
        <h2 style={{ position: 'fixed', top: 0 }}>Scroll {this.state.isTop ? 'down' : 'up'}!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Why is this better?

Comment: because you should not use setState method in componentDidMount hook according to ReactJS Document.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed @PouyaAtaei answer a bit for my use case.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

// Added distance parameter to determine how much 
// from the top tell return value is updated.
// The name of the hook better reflects intended use.
export const useHasScrolled = (distance = 10) => {

  // setting initial value to false
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false)

  // running on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
    // Logic is false tell user reaches threshold, then true after.
      const scrollCheck = window.scrollY >= distance;
      if (scrollCheck !== scroll) {
        setScroll(scrollCheck)
      }
    }

    // setting the event handler from web API
    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)

    // cleaning up from the web API
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
    }

  }, [scroll, setScroll])

  return scroll
}
```

Calling the hook:

```js
const component = () => {
  // calling our custom hook and optional distance agument.
  const scroll = useHasScrolled(250)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another take / my take on **hooks** approach for on scroll displaying and hiding of a random page element.

I have been very much inspired from: [**Dan Abramov**'s post here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

You can check a full working example, in this [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-effect-another-take-on-scroll-hide-e4ot7).

### The following is the code for the useScroll custom hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useScroll = callback => {
  const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = useState(true);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const direction = (() => {
      // if scroll is at top or at bottom return null,
      // so that it would be possible to catch and enforce a special behaviour in such a case.
      if (
        window.pageYOffset === 0 ||
        window.innerHeight + Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset) >=
          document.body.offsetHeight
      )
        return null;
      // otherwise return the direction of the scroll
      return scrollDirection < window.pageYOffset ? "down" : "up";
    })();

    callback(direction);
    setScrollDirection(window.pageYOffset);
  };

  // adding and cleanning up de event listener
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  });
};
```

### And this hook will be consumed like this:

```
  useScroll(direction => {
    setScrollDirection(direction);
  });
```

### A full component using this custom hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CustomElement, { useScroll } from "./element";
import Scrollable from "./scrollable";

function Page() {
  const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = useState(null);

  useScroll(direction => {
    setScrollDirection(direction);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {/* a custom element that implements some scroll direction behaviour */}
      {/* "./element" exports useScroll hook and <CustomElement> */}
      <CustomElement scrollDirection={scrollDirection} />
      {/* just a lorem ipsum long text */}
      <Scrollable />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, rootElement);
```

### And lastly the code for CustomElement:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default props => {
  const [elementVisible, setElementVisible] = useState(true);
  const { scrollDirection } = props;

  // when scroll direction changes element visibility adapts, but can do anything we want it to do
  // U can use ScrollDirection and implement some page shake effect while scrolling
  useEffect(() => {
    setElementVisible(
      scrollDirection === "down"
        ? false
        : scrollDirection === "up"
        ? true
        : true
    );
  }, [scrollDirection]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "#ff0",
        padding: "20px",
        position: "fixed",
        width: "100%",
        display: `${elementVisible ? "inherit" : "none"}`
      }}
    >
      element
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two hooks - one for direction (up/down/none) and one for the actual position

Use like this:

```
useScrollPosition(position => {
    console.log(position)
  })

useScrollDirection(direction => {
    console.log(direction)
  })
```

Here are the hooks:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export const SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN = "SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN"
export const SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP = "SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP"
export const SCROLL_DIRECTION_NONE = "SCROLL_DIRECTION_NONE"

export const useScrollDirection = callback => {
  const [lastYPosition, setLastYPosition] = useState(window.pageYOffset)
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null)

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (timer !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
    setTimer(
      setTimeout(function () {
        callback(SCROLL_DIRECTION_NONE)
      }, 150)
    )
    if (window.pageYOffset === lastYPosition) return SCROLL_DIRECTION_NONE

    const direction = (() => {
      return lastYPosition < window.pageYOffset
        ? SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN
        : SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP
    })()

    callback(direction)
    setLastYPosition(window.pageYOffset)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  })
}

export const useScrollPosition = callback => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    callback(window.pageYOffset)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how to fix :

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
MenuNews

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setScroll(window.scrollY > specify_height_you_want_to_change_after_here);
   });
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach without scroll event listener

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  elementId: string;
  position: string;
}

const useCheckScrollPosition = ({ elementId, position }: Props) => {
  const [isOverScrollPosition, setIsOverScrollPosition] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      "IntersectionObserver" in window &&
      "IntersectionObserverEntry" in window &&
      "intersectionRatio" in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype
    ) {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        setIsOverScrollPosition(entries[0].boundingClientRect.y < 0);
      });
      const flagElement = document.createElement("div");
      flagElement.id = elementId;
      flagElement.className = "scroll-flag";
      flagElement.style.top = position;

      const container = document.getElementById("__next"); // React div id
      const oldFlagElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

      if (!oldFlagElement) container?.appendChild(flagElement);

      const elementToObserve = oldFlagElement || flagElement;
      observer.observe(elementToObserve);
    }
  }, [elementId, position]);

  return isOverScrollPosition;
};

export default useCheckScrollPosition;
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
const isOverScrollPosition = useCheckScrollPosition({
    elementId: "sticky-header",
    position: "10px",
  });
```

`isOverScrollPosition` is a boolean that will be true if you scroll over position provided value (10px) and false if you scroll below it.

This approach will add a flag div in react root.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/