# Need to observe scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onscroll

I am building a landing page with a lot of animations. When I need to animate something I create an event listener to the scroll and attach `onScroll` function, which triggers my animations by setting state.

I currently create less than 10 listeners with 10 functions to check the state.

I would like to create an entity that uses 1 event listener and then all my landing page components should subscribe and get position.

How can I do this?
I am using ES6 and React.

A bit of my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.toggleAppBar();
    addScrollEventListener(this.handleOnTopScroll);
    addScrollEventListener(this.handleFirstScroll);
  }

  handleOnTopScroll = () => {
    let scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop
    if (scrollTop === 0) {
      this.toggleAppBar();
    }
  }

  handleFirstScroll = () => {
    let scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop
    //console.log(scroll);
    if (!scroll) {
      this.toggleAppBar();
      scroll = true
      return
    }
    if (scrollTop === 0) {
      scroll = false
    }
  }
```

Solution works as it is required but I would need to add a bunch more listeners for other components

Comment: You can use `scroll()` events. Ref: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: sorry I dont use jQuery I use only vanilla

Comment: You could use `window.onscroll` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll

Comment: but is it attaching a new event listener every time I call it or observing the scroll on a global scale? I am experiencing scroll lag from all those eventListeners I create

Comment: You need to call `window.onscroll` only once after your page loads.Or if you are binding to specific elements, you need to bind to each element only once. I doubt there could be significant performance issues. Can you post some code?

Comment: It is possible that there is a react specific solution for this that provides better performance.

Comment: React with better performance than vanilla JS? I doubt it.

Comment: I have added a and example of one of the scenarios I use to animate the header component

Comment: @montrealist Well, my knowledge of react JS is limited to a 5 day workshop I half-attempted about a year ago. But I was hoping if shadow DOM helps react in some way. Btw, here are a couple of links for `onScroll` in react: https://gist.github.com/koistya/934a4e452b61017ad611, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726000/5894241

Comment: @user1780729 Why are you calling `addScrollEventListener` twice in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: my design descision to separate conserns one function checks for 1st initial scroll the other checks if the user goes back to 0 position

Comment: You could do that with one event listener, and then call two different functions, one to handle the scroll and other to check if the user has gone back to position zero. Btw, you should probably raise a different question for your performance issues with some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar on our company website, with somewhat complex animations on scroll.  The solution we came up with was to normalize the scroll on a parent component so that 0 scroll = 0 and fully scrolled would equal 1.  We passed the "animationProgress" to child components which could determine how and when to animate.

To do this we use the following:

```
calculateAnimationProgress (target) {
  return mapRange(target.scrollTop, 0, target.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight, 0, 1);
}

//Utility function to map a value to it's corelated value within a given range
const mapRange = (value, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax) => (value - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
```

That gives us a normalized scroll from 0 to 1, so that if the height changes you'll always have a known range, though you may need to re-calculate on window resize etc.

In your child components you can then tweak performance by only allowing them to re-render when they are within a given range of your "animationProgress".

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
  return isInRange(nextProps.animationProgress, 0, 1);
}

//Utility function returns boolean if value within a given range
const isInRange = (val, min, max) => {
  return val >= min && val <= max;
}
```

I hope that helps.  You can check out our results from this approach at http://redshiftdigital.com

Comment: Okay so as I understand you have a high level component that monitors the scroll and then pass that data to child components in which you set the triggers according to the value of scroll.

Comment: Yep, that's right. We ended up tying it all to a GSAP timelines in the components, which also uses 0 to 1 for it's animation progress.  https://greensock.com/timelinemax .

Comment: Just two questions, do you wrap each individual component, let say section 1, section 2 ... with this higher order component, or you wrap the whole app itself and what technique do you youse to pass the actual value to children?

Comment: We have a higher order component wrapping, rather than the whole app.  We felt we had more granular control over what specifically was rendering on each scroll tick, since there are a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With plain JS, you could use [`element.onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll) event to listen to scroll events on specific element.

You may consider using jQuery's [`scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event, if jQuery is available.