# Mouse wheel events in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How do you go about getting mouse wheel events in reactjs?

I have tried onWheel

```
  render: function() {
    return <div onWheel = {this.wheel} >
       < /div>;
  },
```

and I have tried onScroll

```
  render: function() {
    return <div onScroll = {this.wheel} >
       < /div>;
  },
```

But neither of these events are picked up. See the fiddle below :

https://jsfiddle.net/812jnppf/2/

Comment: Theoretically the onWheel synthetic event is what you want to use, I have bare bones create-react-app app, and onWheel works fine for me. I just can't make your jsfiddle work for wheel events, but click events are no problem: https://jsfiddle.net/812jnppf/8/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, your div is 0 height, so you don't scroll on it. You don't have to bind this as it is a class (and not an es6 react component). Just do a call to the function with the event as parameter on onWheel event:

https://jsfiddle.net/812jnppf/9/

```
render: function() {

   return <div style={{height:300, width:300}} onWheel = {(e) => this.wheel(e)} >      < /div>;
},
```

Of course, you have to clean code to style your div with a var or in css.

EDIT : I set it onWheel and not on onScroll (witch doesn't exist I guess ? confirm it if you know). I saw a SO post about adding scroll event to your component easilly : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726000/4099279

Comment: ah of course stupid me. It was on the wrong container. My next question would be how to interpret the y=100 y=-100 events, and how to go about getting zooming effect.

Comment: AFAIK, `(e) => this.wheel(e)` is the same as `this.wheel`, except for creating a new object every time and therefore forcing re-render. +++ `onScroll` exists and works, I'm using it.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the callback to `this`:

```
render: function() {
    return <div onWheel = {this.wheel.bind(this)} >
       < /div>;
}
```