# How to implement the following in the react js way

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks, state

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXUxJ.png)
Hi I am trying to change an image onWheel event and so far the code works in a bad way, can anyone suggest ways to improve. I am trying to recreate the zoom out/in effect as seen on the mrpops.ua/en website. When the wheel event triggers the count increases or decrease on direction. Is there maybe a way to use the number count to do some fancy math instead of using it to change animation name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

If as you say in the comments you have 6 different animations, one way of implementing that would be:

```
const Contact = () => {

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

/* Code for updating the counter */

  const handleWheel = ({ deltaY }) => {
    setCount((currentCount) =>
      deltaY > 0 ? currentCount + 1 : currentCount - 1
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

// I suggest to place all the possible animations in an object, and then retrieve them with object[1], etc. You could also use switch, but this option is cleaner IMO.

const style = {
1: "animation 1"
2: "animation 2"
...
6: "animation 6"
}

return (
      <header onWheel={handleWheel}>
        <img className="header-img" style={{animation: style[count]}}>
        </img>
      </header>
    )}
```

**Original answer**

I'll suggest the following to "translate" the screenshot code into actual React code:

```
const Contact = ({ counter }) => (
  <header>
    <img className="header-img" style={{animation: counter === 1 ? "scaleUp 2s ease forwards" : "scaleUp2 2s ease forwards"}}>
    </img>
  </header>
)
```

Mind that with React you access style as an object, this is why I'm using {} first to let React know I'll insert JS in HTML, and second because it's a object like: {animation: ""}

Another option, without editing the node style directly, is with conditional rendering. Personally, I **prefer this one** more:

```
    const Contact = ({ counter }) => (
      <header>
// We use classes with BEM to apply the specific animations
        {counter === 1 && <img className="header-img header-img--one"></img>}
        {counter === 2 && <img className="header-img header-img--two"></img>}
      </header>
    )
```

About the wheel effect, since you are using a console.logs I'm not sure how do you intend to implement that. However, I'll share a SO link that might help you with that:

[Mouse wheel events in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217642/mouse-wheel-events-in-reactjs)

It is preferable to do as suggested in this post (use onWheel or onScroll) rather than inserting event listeners directly.

The same way, it is also preferable to completely avoid query selectors and any other way of imperative coding (if you are unfamiliar with the terms, Google differences between imperative and declarative programming).

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the help I am starting to understand it better. I tried what I wanted to do again in react and so far I have an counter that increases by 1 when scrolling down and decrease when scrolling up. The problem I have is finding a way to change the css animation based on the counter value. I have six animation that changes the image scale and when the wheel event triggers and the counter increase i want the value to be used as the animation name for ex.    `scaleUP ${ counter }`,  but I cannot acces the animation like in js === img.style.animation = ...

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with your current code? That way I think it would be easier for me and other users to guide you. I assume you don't want to simply use CSS classes to change the animation? If it must be CSS in the style attribute, have you tried my suggestion (first code snippet)?

Comment: Hi no problem the code will be updated.

Comment: Hi I re READ your explanation and think I know what to do thank you very much.

Comment: That's great! I'm going to anyways edit my answer one last time with a suggestion that IMHO could get you a better code.