# onScroll in react only works on the window?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a personal website in react, and I wanted to do some tricks with scrolling, but ya know how it goes, getting stuck on step one. All I have in my react is

```
  class App extends Component {
  makeTextLarger(e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log("scrolling")
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test)
      console.log(list)

      list.addEventListener('scroll', this.makeTextLarger);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
      const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test)
      list.removeEventListener('scroll', this.makeTextLarger);
  }
  render() {
    var style = {
      height: '10000px',
      fontSize: 200,
      background: 'blue'
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title"</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          text to be made bigger at some point
        </p>
        <div ref="test" style={style}>
          Pls
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In which nothing fires as I scroll. If I instead look at use window instead of the specific div, it works. When I console.log the list, it does indeed return an html object, so Im not sure why my binding is working selectively. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to your component that reads the "scroll" event.

For example, here's a rewrite to your component.  Only the methods were changed, no refs were added:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }
  handleScroll = () => {
    this.setState(
      { count: this.state.count + 1 },
      console.log('Scroll', this.state.count)
    )
  }
  render() {
    var style = {
      height: '10000px',
      fontSize: 200,
      background: 'blue'
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title" />
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">text to be made bigger at some point</p>
        <div ref="test" style={style}>
          Pls
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You'll get a steady stream of console.logs to your browser with this.  It should be close to accurate, but not perfect, since `this.setState` is asynchronous.

You can also pass in the event itself with `handleScroll = (e) => {`

For reference: [Update style of a component onScroll in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js)

Answer (score -1):

try using the onScroll handler react offers

```
  render() {
    var style = {
      height: '10000px',
      fontSize: 200,
      background: 'blue'
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title"</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          text to be made bigger at some point
        </p>
        <div onScroll={this. makeTextLarger} style={style}>
          Pls
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

if you insist on using a ref

```
<div ref={ref => this.title = ref} style={style}>
          Pls
</div>
```

then in your lifecycle methods use this.title.

lastly always bind your event handlers

```
makeTextLarger = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    console.log("scrolling")
  }
```