# Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Tags: reactjs

I get this error: `Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`. I use this function `getBoundingClientRect`, because in my project I want to have the following efect: at the moment one element is highlighted, the rest has different styles. The message shows the functions `handleScroll`. The component in which I use looks like this

```
class QuestionListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isActive: false,
    };

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    this.handleScroll();
  };

  handleScroll = () => {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    const { top } = this.wrapRef.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (top > 60 && top < 400 && !isActive) {
      this.setState({ isActive: true });
    }
    if ((top <= 60 || top >= 400) && isActive) {
      this.setState({ isActive: false });
    }
  }

  setWrapRef = (ref) => {
    this.wrapRef = ref;
  }

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    const { question } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={`Test__questions-item--noactive ${isActive && 'Test__questions-item--active'}`}
        ref={this.setWrapRef}
      >
        <li key={question.id}>
          <p>
            {question.question}
          </p>
          <QuestionAnswerForm name={question.question} />
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why is there such a mistake? Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js

Answer (score 2):

As I noticed your code, there you used arrow function with componentDidMount.

It should be:

```
componentDidMount() {}
```

also if you are using arrow function with handleScroll then there is no need to bind in the constructor, try to remove it and then modify the handleScroll as follows:

```
handleScroll = () => {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    if (this.wrapRef) {
       const { top } = this.wrapRef.getBoundingClientRect();
       if (top > 60 && top < 400 && !isActive) {
          this.setState({ isActive: true });
       }
       if ((top <= 60 || top >= 400) && isActive) {
          this.setState({ isActive: false });
       }
    }
  }
```

Also remove function call this.handleScroll() after event listner in the componentDidMount as it is of no use.

Comment: there is no error, however the state is not updated, styles do not change. As if the function `handleScroll` was not called

Comment: @Elder handleScroll only called if there is a scrollbar in your current component, I have no idea of style but there should be fixed height on the div with overflow property so that it has a scrollbar as it is assigned to scroll event listener

Comment: yes its works. I add   componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
and everything is ok :)

Comment: @Elder, please accept the answer if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have not created any `ref` for `wrapRef`. as the Error says cannot get the property of null; so the `wrapRef` itself is null

```
class QuestionListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isActive: false,
    };

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    this.handleScroll();
  };

  wrapRef=React.createRef();

  handleScroll = () => {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    const { top } = this.wrapRef.current.style;
    if (top > 60 && top < 400 && !isActive) {
      this.setState({ isActive: true });
    }
    if ((top <= 60 || top >= 400) && isActive) {
      this.setState({ isActive: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    const { question } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={`Test__questions-item--noactive ${isActive && 'Test__questions-item--active'}`}
        ref={this.wrapRef}
      >
        <li key={question.id}>
          <p>
            {question.question}
          </p>
          <QuestionAnswerForm name={question.question} />
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what I should change

Comment: Edited the Answer

Comment: also pay attention to `ref={this.wrapRef}` in your `div`

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the foo.getBoundingClientRect() inside a useEffect, which reads it when the component mounts. I was getting the same error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).