# ReactJS custom cursor effect:Cursor not working when user scroll

Tags: reactjs

Those days I watch in youtube great  [**video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfpRZ2t_BrQ&t=9s) how to create custom cursor CSS and JS.

So I wrote this code in ReactJS and create  almost similar custom cursor effect.But there and small bug when user scroll (without move mouse only scroll) my custom cursor not moving.

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-panini-jcjj5)

Please help how to solve this issue.

```
state = {
    xMain: 0,
    yMain: 0,
    expand: false
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.expand) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ expand: false });
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  handleMouseMove = e => {
    const { pageX, pageY } = e;

    this.setState({
      xMain: pageX,
      yMain: pageY
    });
  };
  expandCursor = () => {
    this.setState({
      expand: true
    });
  };
  render = () => {
    const { xMain, yMain } = this.state;

    return (
      <div
        className="container"
        onClick={this.expandCursor}
        onMouseMove={e => this.handleMouseMove(e)}
      >
        <div
          className={this.state.expand ? "cursor expand" : "cursor"}
          style={{
            left: xMain,
            top: yMain
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have write [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-tdd-pnxqd?fontsize=14).

It has a little delay while scrolling, which is about the performance issue. I haven't come up the way to fix.

Anyway, still hope this helps!

In my opinion, to achieve this needs to consider 2 steps:

1. Add a scroll event listener

   In your code, to add `onScroll` in `.container` will not working, because when you scroll, only `body` element can detect this event.

   Hence we have two ways available:

   a. Bind vanilla Javascript eventList in lifecycles [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js).

   b. Make your element scrollable, and bind `onScroll` in JSX.

   In my code I tried b method. The key is to create a  `parent wrapper(position: relative; width: 100%;)` for `container`, and add the style `height: 100%;` to `html, body, #root`. I have to say I don't know the real reason why add `height: 100%;` would make this work. I learn this by `react-sprint` [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/py912w5k6m).
2. Get the scroll offset for the event, and calculate the position of cursor.

   Once the onScroll works, the second thing is : how to calculate the cursor position form scroll event?

   I notice that previous `wrap` approach made the `pageX`, `pageY` value changes. 
   The value is not the offset to the document anymore, it's the offset to the viewport. (I guess it only count in the scroll offset with body.)

   And we can use `scrollTop` value of scroll event to get the scroll offset from the document:

   > scrollTop
   >
   > The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that an element's content is scrolled vertically.

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

   Last step, defined the `x,y`  properties for scroll event and mouse event individually, then sum up the `scrollX` and `mouseY`  as `left`; sum up the `scrollY`(the scrolled height) and `mouseY` (the y offset of mouse from viewport) as `top`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the scroll event. Try something like this.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.expand) {
      setTimeout(_ => {
        this.setState({ expand: false });
      }, 500);
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = e => {
    console.log('x');

    this.setState({
      xMain: e.pageX,
      yMain: e.pageY
    });
  };
```