# Change Toolbar background color with react when body scolled

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change toolbar background color as `#fff` color when body scrolled.Otherwise it will be `transparent`.

Here is sample toolbar component:

```
export default class ToolBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      scrolled:false
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { children, className,scrolled, ...other } = this.props
    return (
      <nav style={{backgroundColor:this.state.scrolled?'#fff':'transparent'}}>
        {children}
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

How can we do this with react?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update style of a component onScroll in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js)

Comment: No its about effect. But I try for background color.

Comment: The duplicate shows how to attach an `onscroll` listener and use it to change state, which is exactly what you need to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event listener to window object.

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkScroll);
}

checkScroll = () => {
   this.setState({ scrolled: window.scrollY > 0 });
};
```

**Note**: You would probably also need some debounce to avoid rapid and multiple set states.

And remember to disconnect the listener on component destroy.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.checkScroll);
}
```

Comment: working good. I just wonder this how the state is checking if scrolling ended?

Comment: @kodcu It just fires with every scroll event, that's why you will need some debounce :)