# How to change navbar background color in react when I scroll

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to make my navbar start out as transparent but when a user scrolls the navbar will change color / background-color. I am using a bootstrap navbar and react.

jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/nav.scss';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'react-bootstrap';

class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg ">
        <NavLink
          to="/"
          class="navbar-brand"
          activeClassName="navbar-brand--active"
        >
          Web_Env
        </NavLink>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                Create post
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                to="/login"
                className="nav-link"
                activeClassName="nav-link--active"
              >
                Login
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                to="/register"
                className="nav-link"
                activeClassName="nav-link--active"
              >
                Register
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

css code:

```
$color1: #aceca1;
$bgcolor1: #629460;
.navbar {
  background-color: $bgcolor1 !important;
  .navbar-brand {
    color: lighten($color1, 10%);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    .navbar-brand--active {
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  }

  .nav-link {
    color: $color1;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    transition: 200ms;
  }
  .nav-link--active {
    color: white !important;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    font-weight: 10px;
  }
  .nav-link:hover {
    color: white !important;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-weight: 10px;
  }
}
```

I have looked at a previous post about this from 2 years ago but being a beginner I didn't really understand any of it. If possible an explanations  alongside the code would help me very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update style of a component onScroll in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js)

Answer (score 11):

Here is An Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-newton-f4j0j

you can use `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`
for detecting how much user scroll from top of the page.
in this case 120 from top.

you put this into the `componentDidMount` and save this in a variable so u can remove this listener later in `ComponentWillUnmount`.

and because this listener fired up each time scroll occurs it is good for having a better performance we check the value of the state and updated it just when it's necessary.

```
this.listener = document.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
      var scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
      if (scrolled >= 120) {
        if (this.state.status !== "amir") this.setState({ status: "amir" })
      } else {
        if (this.state.status !== "top") this.setState({ status: "top" })
    }
 });
```

For anyone needs a solution using functional-based components

```
  let listener = null
  const [scrollState, setScrollState] = useState("top")

  useEffect(() => {
    listener = document.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
      var scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop
      if (scrolled >= 120) {
        if (scrollState !== "amir") setScrollState("amir")
      } else {
        if (scrollState !== "top") setScrollState("top")
      }
    })
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", listener)
    }
  }, [scrollState])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      const backgroundcolor = window.scrollY < 100 ? "red" : "blue";

      this.setState({ navBackground: backgroundcolor });
    });
  }
```

to your code.

> The **scroll** event fires when the document view or an element has been scrolled.
>   
> check this [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-bkn6x)

Answer (score 0):

In js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      let header = document.querySelector('.Header');
      if (window.scrollY > 150) {
        header?.classList.add('scrolled');
      } else {
        header?.classList.remove('scrolled');
      }
    },[]);
```

In Css

```
.Header {
  /* How it will look before scrolled */
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #002241 !important;

  /* To give smoote change */
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-out .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-out .5s;
  transition: all ease-out .5s;
}
.Header.scrolled {
  /* How it will look when scrolled */
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

The header itself:

```
    <div className='Header'>
      The Header content
    </div>
```