# Change style of header component on scroll on home page only in React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used the following approach to change the style of my header on scroll which is working fine. Referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726000/9496077)

```
  state = {
    scrolled: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const isTop = window.scrollY < 84
      if (!isTop) {
        this.setState({
          scrolled: true
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          scrolled: false
        })
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll')
  }
```

The problem is that it works on every route(component) as I have the header component included in the App.js file but I want it to work specifically on the Home page only.

Is there a way to check the current route and perform this transition on header, only for the home component which will work with my current approach or do I need to change my approach altogether?

Comment: use `window.location.pathname` to conditionally add this listener

Comment: @dixitk13 This doesn't work as the componentDidMount() is only called once and the location.pathname doesn't update even if the route changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method for handling scroll and refer it in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. But in your example, you are not referring it. You can use it like the below code sample.

And you should use a condition to match URL that works only on home page.

```js
state = {
    scrolled: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    const isTop = window.scrollY < 84
    if (!isTop) {
      this.setState({
        scrolled: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        scrolled: false
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: I have put the check to match URL inside the componentDidUpdate(), but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: add the condition check in `handleScroll` function, if condition is false return immediately

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use [React Router's location for this use case](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md) and check in its `pathName` property where you are currently routed in your app.

Also be aware that **binding function to `scroll` events can be very costly performance-wise** -just add a console log and scroll and you'll see that it's being called a lot - and you'd like to prefer either another solution depending on what you're trying to achieve.

If you can't avoid passing a function to your `scroll` events you could use libraries such as [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) to debounce the function calls and avoid that it's being called too many times for nothing and potentially impact your performances.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/throttle

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debounce

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you could also use the native [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) which is already optimised.

Comment: Yes, Intersection Observer might be a better option. Just saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxnV9Xcw914) video, but can you throw some light on how this can be achieved in React as the DOM nodes concerned (Header and node to be observed) are in different components.

Comment: Here's an article showing you how https://medium.com/the-non-traditional-developer/how-to-use-an-intersectionobserver-in-a-react-hook-9fb061ac6cb5