# drop shadow not showing when scrolled in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in javascript react. I'm trying to implement when user scrolled down, the navbar would drop a shadow. but unfortunately it doesn't work at all, what did I do wrong??

I think there's a problem with my logic, or perhaps I do the whole code wrongly, if there's an problem with the code, please do tell me where did I do it wrong, thank you

[image: Value of windows.scroll]

The Code :

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super(); // super allows you to access parent class's methods and allows us to use "this." in constructor().
        this.state = {
            clicked: false,
            scrolled: false,
        }
        // Note here too these bindings are necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        // In general, we use binding whenever we use "setState" when handling an event
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleScroll = () => {
        const offset = window.scrollY;
        if (offset > 200) {
            this.setState({scrolled : !this.state.scrolled})
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='mycontainer' onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
                {/* Note here this.scroll.scrolled changes to this.state.scrolled */}
                <nav className={this.state.scrolled ? "NavbarItems Scroll" : "NavbarItems"}>
                    <h1 className="navbar-logo">React <i className="fab fa-react"></i></h1>
                    <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <i className={this.state.clicked ? "fas fa-times" : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        {
                            MenuItems.map((items, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <li key = {index}><a className={items.cName} href={items.url}>
                                        {items.title}
                                    </a></li>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <p>{window.scrollY}</p>
                </nav>

            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

css :

```
.mycontainer {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
}


.NavbarItems {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 85px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.2s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}
.Scroll {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to subscribe to window.onScroll not for div className='mycontainer'

reed this topic
[Update style of a component onScroll in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js)

and (it not related to your problem)
you shouldn't use

```
 this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
 this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

if you use class properties

```
handleScroll = () => {
    ...
  }
handleClick = () => {
    ...
}
```

read this doc
[https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance](http://%20you%20need%20to%20subscribe%20to%20window.onScroll%20not%20for%20div%20className=%27mycontainer%27%20reed%20this%20topic%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js%20%20and%20(it%20not%20related%20to%20your%20problem)%20%20you%20shouldn%27t%20use%20%20%20%20this.handleScroll%20=%20this.handleScroll.bind(this);%20%20%20this.handleClick%20=%20this.handleClick.bind(this);%20if%20you%20use%20class%20properties%20%20%20handleScroll%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%09...%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20handleClick%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%09...%20%20%20%7D%20%20read%20this%20doc%20%20%20https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance)

Comment: i know i'm being lazy, but is it possible to show it? i still don't get it

Comment: is it like this? <nav className={this.state.scrolled ? "NavbarItems Scroll" : "NavbarItems"} onScroll={this.handleScroll}>

because if it is, it's not working